# setHours method not working as expected in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I am trying to change the hours in my `React` app using the `setHours` method:

```js
function App() {
    let currHour = new Date().setHours(15);

    return (
    <div>
        <h1>{currHour}</h1>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Instead of getting 15 as my output I am getting is: **1667813785897**.

Why am I getting this unexpected output?

Comment: Because your rendering the return value of `setHours`, did you mean to do 2 separate calls?.  `let currHour = new Date(); currHour.setHours(15);`

Comment: `let currHour = new Date(); currHour.setHours(15);` gives the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) of `setHours` and focus on the return, then it's saying it's returning the number of milliseconds since Jaunary 1st 1970 00:00:00:

[image]

so the result you are receiving is actually expected. Let's see a snippet which should prove to be helpful:

```js
let dt = new Date();
console.log(`The current date is ${dt}`);
console.log(`Hours before setting the hours to 15 were ${dt.getHours()}`);
let millisecondsSince1970 = dt.setHours(15);
console.log(`After setting the hours to 15, the modified date is ${dt}`);
console.log(`Hours after setting the hours to 15 are ${dt.getHours()}`);
console.log(`Milliseconds since January 1st 1970 00:00:00 are ${millisecondsSince1970}`);
console.log(`Milliseconds since January 1st 1970 00:00:00 converted back to Date is ${new Date(millisecondsSince1970)}`);
```

As you can see, we can get both the dates and the hours

So, instead of getting the result of `setHours` you can do something like this to set the hours to 15 and return them:

```
let currDate = new Date();
currDate.setHours(15);
let currHours = currDate.getHours();
```

or, if you did not even want to set the hours, then you can simply say

```
let currHours = new Date.getHours();
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple things, `currHour` is a `Date` object, so rendering it is going to just call the `toString` method, which is just going to output the milliseconds or something. If you want `15` then you'll want to render `currHour.getHours()`.
Also, `currHour` is going to be set to `new Date().setHours(15)` every time `App` is rendered, which is probably undesirable. Maybe it should be state? Or in a `ref`? I'm not sure what your use case is.

Comment: **Couple things, currHour is a Date object**   Actually is not, its' a number.

Comment: for the same reason `currHour.getHours()` will throw an error, use `new Date( currHour).getHours()` instead

Comment: oh dang, didn't realize that `setHours` didn't return a new `Date` object. Thanks all.